# Jquery ajax call using When and then

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do I post values to test.aspx using the code below

```
$.when( $.ajax( "test.aspx" ) ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
  alert( jqXHR.status ); // Alerts 200
});
```

Also how do i get the response received from the server?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'phpFile.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {"val":selectedVal},
        cache: false
    }).done(function(html){ $( "#name" ).html(html); });
```

Try something like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this:

$.ajax({
                    url: '/WebServices/test.aspx',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        method: 'AddNotice',
                        args:
                            { NoticeDescription: strNotice, CreateDate: CreateDate, EditDate: EditDate, Operator: Operator, NoticeTitle: NoticeTitle, CompanyList: CompanyList }
                    },
                    success: function (data) {

                    }
                });
```